# Resist app to show in installed apps android

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

> I am trying to create a GalleryHide app. I am succesful in removing my app Icon from Home Screen.

But it doesn't remove when I open any **app Manager app.** Is it possible to remove our `package Detail`

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

and with the help of `ApplicationInfo`. Apps read my **appIcon,packageName** and open my hidden app. How could I resist them to show my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove our package Detail

No.

> How could I resist them to show my app.

Do not ship the app.

Comment: Ware Or is it possible to remove app task from runningTask in background.

Comment: @Nepster: No, for blindingly obvious security reasons.